# Python: Create a function that takes dimensions & scaling factor. Returns a two-dimensional array multiplication table scaled by the scaling factor

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to create a function that does what the title is asking for. Without the use of any functions besides: range, len or append. The function would take the dimensional input of the 2D array, as well as the scaling factor, and then return a two-dimensional array multiplication table scaled by the scaling factor.[image: Shown here]

I have tried various different code but have left them out because they return 0 progress on test cases.

Comment: I'm asking where to get started. I didn't ask for code. Algorithms and conceptual starting points are more than helpful for me and I appreciate any help given.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I apologize for not putting this in the right section. The user that provided his answer helped me better understand the application of the dimensions and scaling factors by allowing me to look at it through a retrospective lens. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the output as a 2d array, you can use this:

```
def MatrixTable(width, height, scaling_factor):
    return [[w*h*scaling_factor for w in range(1, width+1)] for h in range(1, height+1)]

MatrixTable(5, 3, 1)
```

Outputs:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]]
```